# Keep GIF animation running while doing calculations

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, pyqt4

I am trying to improve the user experience by showing a load mask above the active QMainWindow/QDialog when performing tasks that takes some time. I have managed to get it working as I want it, except for a moving GIF when performing the task. If I leave the load mask on after the task is complete, the GIF starts moving as it should.

My class for the load mask:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from dlgLoading_view import Ui_dlgLoading

class dlgLoading(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_dlgLoading):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self,parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint))
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, parent.frameGeometry().width(), parent.frameGeometry().height())
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);")

        movie = QtGui.QMovie("loader.gif")
        self.lblLoader.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()

    def showEvent(self, event):
        QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
        super(dlgLoading, self).showEvent(event)

    def setMessage(self,message):
        self.lblMessage.setText(message)
```

The Ui_dlgLoading contains two labels and some vertical spacers: lblLoader (will contain the gif) and lblMessage (will contain a message if needed)

I create the load mask with this code:

```
loadmask = dlgLoading(self)
loadmask.setMessage('Reading data... Please wait')
loadmask.show()
```

I figured I needed some multithreading/multiprocessing, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do it. I read somewhere that you can't tamper with the GUIs threading, so I would need to move the heavy task there instead, but I'm still blank.

As a simple example, let's say I am trying to load a huge file into memory:

```
file = open(dataFilename, 'r')
self.dataRaw = file.read()
file.close()
```

Around that I would create and close my load mask dialog. How do I start the file read without halting the GIF animation?

The GUI is for running some heavy external exe files, so it should work with that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
class runthread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, commandline, cwd):
        self.stdout = None
        self.stderr = None
        self.commandline = commandline
        self.cwd = cwd
        self.finished = False
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        subprocess.call(self.commandline, cwd=self.cwd)
        self.finished = True

class command()
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def run():
        ...

        thread = runthread("\"%s\" \"%s\"" % (os.path.join(self.__caller.exefolder, "%s.exe" % self.__cmdtype), self.__name), self.__caller.exeWorkdir)
        thread.start()

        count = 0
        sleeptime = 0.5
        maxcount = 60.0/sleeptime
        while True:
            time.sleep(sleeptime)
            QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()
            count += 1
            if thread.finished:
                break
            if count >= maxcount:
                results = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self.__caller, "Continue?", "The process is taking longer than expected. Do you want to continue?", QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
                if results == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
                    count == 0
                else:
                    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self.__caller, "Process stopped", "The process was stopped")
                    return False
```

It actually doesn't directly answer my question, but it worked for me, so I'm posting the answer if others want to do something similar.

I call a process (in this case Pythons subprocess.call) through a thread and track when the process is actually finished. A continuous loop checks periodically if the process is done and updates the GUI (processEvents - this is what triggers the GIF to update). To avoid an infinite loop I offer the user an option to exit after some time.