# Creating a lot of QObject's with signals inside a QThread

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, pyside6

I was messing around with an application that has a save/load function. Both reading the saved file and loading all the components takes enough time to halt the program for a bit. I found out that while I can read the saved file, I should [avoid creating any QObjects inside the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516040/pyqt-signal-for-object-created-in-different-thread-doesnt-work) (the objects needs signals, hence QObject). To fix this, I emit the contents of the saved file and handle creating objects outside, but since the creation of objects *also* takes some time, I am not ready to give up on the idea.

I have re-created a minimal working example, that shows the problem. The objects are created correctly either way - normally or threaded - however, the signals are not emitted (or emitting into the void in a thread that has now been garbage collected). I use(d) this pattern in my application, except I emit the stuff I need from the thread and to stuff, instead of doing stuff inside the thread.

If this truly is just a bad idea and against good programming practice, just tell me and I will have to adjust or live with a stuttering GUI. The reason why I am keen on avoiding these stutters is because I utilize a spinning loader-gif on heavy operations and it keeps running it I perform the heavy stuff in a separate thread (come to think of it, maybe the gif can run in its own thread instead...?)

```
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class SomeParentContainer(QtCore.QObject):
    some_signal = QtCore.Signal(str)
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = list()
        super().__init__()


class SomeObjectWithSignals(QtCore.QObject):
    some_signal = QtCore.Signal(str)
    
    def __init__(self, parent, dummy_id):
        self.parent = parent
        self.dummy_id = dummy_id
        super().__init__()
        self.some_signal.connect(lambda dummy_id: self.parent.some_signal.emit(dummy_id))

    def fake_emit(self):
        self.some_signal.emit(self.dummy_id)
        
        
container_obj = SomeParentContainer()     
        
        
class SomeMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        container_obj.some_signal.connect(lambda dummy_id: print(f"some_signal emitted from child: {dummy_id}"))
        
        self.main_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        btn.clicked.connect(self.btn1)
        btn.setText("Add normally")
        self.layout.addWidget(btn)
        
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        btn.clicked.connect(self.btn2)
        btn.setText("Add threaded")
        self.layout.addWidget(btn)
        
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        btn.clicked.connect(self.btn3)
        btn.setText("Emit signals")
        self.layout.addWidget(btn)
        
        self.main_widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        
    def btn1(self):
        container_obj.container.append(SomeObjectWithSignals(container_obj, "test1"))
        
    def btn2(self):
        class SomeThreadedAction(QtCore.QThread):
            finished = QtCore.Signal()
            
            def run(self):
                container_obj.container.append(SomeObjectWithSignals(container_obj, "test2"))
        self.thread = SomeThreadedAction()
        self.thread.finished.connect(lambda: print("thread finished"))
        self.thread.start()
        
    def btn3(self):
        for objects in container_obj.container:
            print("Should be emitting something next:")
            objects.fake_emit()
            print("-------------------------")


app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
form = SomeMainWindow()
form.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Give up on the idea. It won't work, and probably wouldn't help anyway. This means your question is currently framed as an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), because it asks about your attempted solution, rather than your actual problem. I suggest you re-write it accordingly, and provide a proper [mre]. There are probably ways to improve your application, but without a realistic example, it's diffcult to give concrete advice.

Comment: Funny you should mention it, this is more or less the same thing I asked almost 7 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860694/keep-gif-animation-running-while-doing-calculations. 

The X problem I have is that I don't want users to think the application has crashed (because everything freezes or 1-2 seconds). I don't *need* threads, but they keep the animation running smoothly.

Comment: *"I should avoid creating any QObjects inside the thread"*, why? I see no problems with that. It's just QWidgets which must be in the main GUI thread.

Comment: Indeed, it seems like you're asking the wrong question, and you're also basing your ideas on wrong assumptions: 1. there is absolutely *nothing* wrong in creating QObjects in other threads, the only problem you may have if those objects are used across threads and they are not thread safe; 2. *some* objects cannot (or should not) be created in threads, specifically, UI elements (and, especially, widgets) can **not** be created in external threads; 3. UI elements are not thread-safe, and should *never* be accessed from external threads. So, no, you cannot "run the gif" in its own thread, ->

Comment: -> not only because you cannot create, access or show it from outside the main thread, but it would also be pointless: even ignoring the fact that you can't, it wouldn't make sense, because if the GIF thread is able to run, then also the main one is. What you *could* do, instead, is to periodically release control from the worker thread (eg. through `time.sleep()` or `QThread.sleep()`) so that the UI is properly able to perform its duties (aka, process its event queue and eventually draw widgets that need it, including those using animations).

Comment: Also note that the signal connection in `SomeObjectWithSignals` is conceptually wrong for many reasons: 1. it shouldn't be responsibility of a child to connect itself to a parent function or signal; 2. connecting to lambdas must **always** be done with care, especially when dealing with threading; 3. there's little point in connecting a signal to another like that especially considering that they share the same signature, just connect to the signal itself: `self.some_signal.connect(self.parent.some_signal)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend sharing `QObject` instances between threads because it will make your code unnecessarily complex. It will be much more simple, if you transfer a result of pure Python objects from the worker thread into the main thread, and create `QObject` instances from the result in the main thread.

But if you insist on transfering `QObject` instances, you have to care about these points.

1. You should change the thread affinity of a `QObject` instance. See [Per-thread Event Loop](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/threads-qobject.html#per-thread-event-loop).
2. You should give a correct hint on a signal receiver when you call the `connect()`. If you do not specify a slot of a `QObject` instance, a dummy receiver with an affinity to the calling thread will be created.
3. You should keep a `QObject` instance alive until the receiving thread owns it.

So, you can do like the following.

```
...
class SomeParentContainer(QtCore.QObject):
    ...
    def emit_some_signal(self, dummy_id):
        self.some_signal.emit(dummy_id)

class SomeObjectWithSignals(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent, dummy_id):
        ...
        #self.some_signal.connect(lambda dummy_id: self.parent.some_signal.emit(dummy_id))
        self.moveToThread(parent.thread()) # The point #1.
        self.some_signal.connect(parent.emit_some_signal) # The point #2.
        self.setParent(parent) # The point #3.
...
class SomeMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    ...
    def btn2(self):
        class SomeThreadedAction(QtCore.QThread):
            #finished = QtCore.Signal() # It's bad to override the QThread.finished.
            obj_created = QtCore.Signal(QtCore.QObject)
            def run(self):
                #container_obj.container.append(SomeObjectWithSignals(container_obj, "test2"))
                # It's bad to update the state of an object
                # owned by the main thread in a worker thread.
                self.obj_created.emit(SomeObjectWithSignals(container_obj, "test2"))
        self.thread = SomeThreadedAction()
        self.thread.finished.connect(lambda: print("thread finished"))
        self.thread.obj_created.connect(container_obj.container.append)
        self.thread.start()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of fiddling and trying to make it work with QtCore.Signal's and threads, I decided to implement my own Non-Qt signals.

This will probably cause me more problems down the line, but I have to finish this project.

If anybody finds this post and wants to try on their own, this is what I ended up with:

```
class QueuedSignal:
    num_queues = 0
    _queue = []

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args
        self.blocked = False
        self._slots = []

    def connect(self, slot):
        if type(slot) is QueuedSignal:
            slot = slot.emit
        if callable(slot):
            self._slots.append(slot)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Slot must be callable")

    def emit(self, *args):
        if self.blocked:
            return
        self.check_args(*args)
        for slot in self._slots:
            if self.num_queues > 0:
                self.add_to_queue(slot, args)
            else:
                self.fire(slot, args)

    def check_args(self, *args):
        if len(args) != len(self.args):
            raise TypeError(f"QueuedSignal expected {len(self.args)} signal(s) but {len(args)} were given.")

        types = tuple(type(arg) for arg in args)
        for type_, expected in zip(types, self.args):
            if not issubclass(type_, expected):
                raise TypeError(f"QueuedSignal expected {self.args} but got {types}")

    def queued(self, is_queued):
        if is_queued:
            QueuedSignal.num_queues = QueuedSignal.num_queues + 1
        else:
            QueuedSignal.num_queues = max(0, QueuedSignal.num_queues - 1)

        if QueuedSignal.num_queues == 0:
            self.empty_queue()

    def block_signals(self, is_blocked):
        self.blocked = is_blocked

    @classmethod
    def queued(cls, is_queued):
        if is_queued:
            cls.num_queues = cls.num_queues + 1
        else:
            cls.num_queues = max(0, cls.num_queues - 1)

        if cls.num_queues == 0:
            cls.empty_queue()

    @classmethod
    def add_to_queue(cls, slot, args):
        cls._queue.append((slot, args))

    @classmethod
    def empty_queue(cls):
        queue = []
        for signal in cls._queue:
            if signal not in queue:
                queue.append(signal)
        for slot, args in queue:
            cls.fire(slot, args)
        cls._queue.clear()

    @staticmethod
    def fire(slot, args):
        signature = inspect.signature(slot)
        parameters = signature.parameters
        num_parameters = len(parameters)
        if num_parameters == 0 or any(parameter.kind != parameter.VAR_POSITIONAL for parameter in parameters.values()):
            args = args[:num_parameters]
        slot(*args)
```